# Storybook fails on eslint errors in react

Tags: reactjs, eslint, storybook

I have configured React, Storybook, Tailwind. everything worked properly. But After I added eslint it breaks storybook for every eslint errors.

### .storybook/main.js

```js
    const path = require('path');
    
    module.exports = {
      stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
      addons: [
        '@storybook/addon-links',
        '@storybook/addon-essentials',
        '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
      ],
      webpackFinal: async (config) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader',
              options: {
                ident: 'postcss',
                plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')],
              },
            },
          ],
          include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
        });
        
        return config;
      },
    };
```

### Error

[ESLintError:
src/stories/Button.js
Line 2:23:  'prop-types' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S prop-types' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies

src/stories/Header.js
Line 2:23:  'prop-types' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S prop-types' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies

src/stories/Page.js
Line 2:23:   'prop-types' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S prop-types' to add it  import/no-extraneous-dependencies
Line 28:11:  `"` can be escaped with `&quot;`, `&ldquo;`, `&#34;`, `&rdquo;`                                   react/no-unescaped-entities
Line 28:16:  `"` can be escaped with `&quot;`, `&ldquo;`, `&#34;`, `&rdquo;`                                   react/no-unescaped-entities

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.]

WARN Broken build, fix the error above.
WARN You may need to refresh the browser.

error Command failed with exit code 1.

Comment: there is only postCSS in your code snippet, without ESLint plugin - could you add ESLint as well, taking into account popularity of your question?

Answer (score 6):

In my case I just wanted to disabled eslint errors during development so

```
DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true start-storybook -p 6006 -s public
```

did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question, I was struggling with this issue for a couple of hours...

The steps of my investigation are the following:

1. display the existing Webpack config:

```js
      webpackFinal: async (config) => {
        console.log(config);
```

2. analyse configuration

```js
  bail: false,
  stats: { preset: 'none', logging: 'error' },
```

3. the `bail` parameter is `false` what's fine, but `preset: 'none'` means to show nothing - let's park it, we will need it later
   proof: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#stats-presets
4. by default the ESLintPlugin throws errors and fails
   proof: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/eslint-webpack-plugin/#failonerror
5. trying to change the parameter `failOnError` to `false`, e.g.

```js
      new ESLintPlugin({
        context: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'),
        overrideConfigFile: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '.eslintrc'),
        extensions: ['js', 'jsx'],
        files: ['./components', './theme'],
        failOnError: false,
      })
```

6. Now we can see warnings if we change the `stats` parameters:

```js
  webpackFinal: async config => {
    config.stats = undefined;
    config.plugins.push(
```

Answer (score 0):

Running storybook with the [ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/) option also does the trick:

```
ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true npm run storybook
```

You can also set it and forget it as a storybook [environment variable](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/environment-variables).

Answer (score -2):

this is happened because ESLint is throwing errors instead of warnings!
and storybook can not start with that errors.
you have two ways to solve this problem!!

1. set 'warn' for all of the rules that you are using in your ESLint config file
2. use this package https://github.com/bfanger/eslint-plugin-only-warn to change all of rules to 'warn' automatically.